# What is the difference between these initializations?

Tags: c++, initialization

I used to know that uninitialized member variables are initialized with a garbage value.

But, If there is a pointer variable uninitialized in a class, all of the uninitialized member variables are initialized with zero.

I think the pointer variable is just pointing an instance in heap memory.

Why are other variables changed?

I don't know what the difference is between these initializations.

Below is the code I tried for step by step.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Test {
private:
    int val1;
    int val2;

public:
    void PrintValue() {
        cout << "val1: " << val1 << endl;
        cout << "val2: " << val1 << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Test a;
    a.PrintValue();
}
```

then, the result is

```
val1: -858993460
val2: -858993460
```

In this code, I added **'int* ptr = new int'** like below.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Test {
private:
    int val1;
    int val2;
    int* ptr = new int;

public:
    void PrintValue() {
        cout << "val1: " << val1 << endl;
        cout << "val2: " << val1 << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Test a;
    a.PrintValue();
}
```

The result is like this.

```
val1: 0
val2: 0
```

Why does this happen?

I'm using VS community 2019 and build tools v142.

Comment: how is `0` not garbage? Btw uninitialized is unitialized, there is no such thing as "initialized with garbage"

Comment: uninitialized member variables are not initialized with a garbage value. They are not initialized at all. Thats why they are called uninitialized. They will have whatever value happened to be in that memory from it's last use.

Comment: @Eric - Spot on.    The expectation that uninitialised variables will end up with "garbage values"  (where "garbage" isn't well defined, but is often interpreted as "not zero") would have to be one of the dumbest phenomena among C and C++ developers.   It's a sign that there is too much lousy teaching material (yes, I've seen plenty) and too many lousy teachers, out there

Comment: It must be accepted this as happened by chance and assumed that it is something implementation detail of the msvc and should not be trusted. Probably reason is the bytes at those locations represents zero by chance ( if msvc leaves the memory as is ).

Comment: Are you compiling in debug or release mode in VS?

Comment: @Jake - I did it in debug mode.

Answer (score 5):

Nothing changed. As the effect of [default initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization), the data member `val1` and `val2` will be initialized to indeterminate value; any use of them leads to UB, anything is possible.

> otherwise, nothing is done: the objects with automatic storage duration (and their subobjects) are initialized to indeterminate values.
>
> Default initialization of non-class variables with automatic and dynamic storage duration produces objects with indeterminate values

Answer (score 1):

The difference here is that adding the `int* ptr = new int` changes your class under the hood from a `POD`(plain old data) class to a `non-POD` class.
If you try with your first example

```
class Test {
public:
    int val1;
    int val2;

    void PrintValue() {
        cout << "val1: " << val1 << endl;
        cout << "val2: " << val1 << endl;
    }
};

int main() {

    Test t;
    cout << t.val1 << endl;
}
```

Then you will get a compiler error because it knows you are trying to access uninitialized variables.

However, when you add the more complex `int* ptr = new int` then your class becomes non-POD and so the compiler creates a default constructor for you, which will initialize your variables for you.
Therefore

```
class Test {
public:
    int val1;
    int val2;
    int* ptr = new int;
    void PrintValue() {
        cout << "val1: " << val1 << endl;
        cout << "val2: " << val1 << endl;
    }
};

int main() {

    Test t;
    cout << t.val1 << endl;
}
```

This becomes legal and will now compile 
(although as other answers pointed out, while the output of this may look cleaner, and it won't throw an error, accessing these default initialed variables may still be UB)

[more info on POD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/PODType)